# A sphere on a friction less surface with a shifted center of mass

Tags: newtonian-gravity, torque

So I'm trying to determine if a sphere at rest on a friction less surface shifts its center of mass internally if it would move or simply spin in place. Lets say BB-8 for the Force Awakens just happens to be on a perfect sheet of ice. Can he move if he shifted his center of gravity or would be be stuck in place?

Edit: I incorrectly used center of gravity, I meant center of mass.

Comment: How to shift the center of gravity of a sphere? A non spherical Object (BB8) would just fall over if any torque would be present.  I do not really understand what you are asking.

Comment: That's because I made a terrible error. I meant center of mass. I would assume you have a weight internally that could move.

Answer (score 2):

The laws of motion state clearly that for the center of mass to accelerate in any direction there must be a net *external* force applied in this direction.

Without friction and in the absence of other external forces (jet pack, etc) if he shifts his weight around the parts will move such that the location of the center of mass will remain still.

Although the motion of a single rigid body can be very complex, the motion of its center of mass is governed only by $\sum \vec{F} = m \vec{a}_{cm}$ and thus very simple.

See demo of the motion of the CM of a tennis racket tossed in the air [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DY3LYQv22qY).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about cases where the center of gravity coincides with the center of mass. That is the gravity is practically the same throughout the body.
If there is no friction, and no surfaces with a normal component to the direction you would like to move there will be no external forces on the body. (Gravity is assumed orthogonal to the ground.) With no external forces there can be no acceleration and the body will stay still or stay in motion if it already has a velocity. This is due to Newtons second law of motion. $\Sigma F = m\cdot a$. The left side is zero, which means the acceleration is zero. This means you can't change your center of mass/gravity.

However, you can still move your bodyparts, but then the other parts of your body will move in opposite direction, maintaining your centre of mass. That is, if you throw your arms out to the side, your body is sliding slightly to the other side. If you pull your arms back, you slide back to your original position. You are stuck.

If you ever find yourself in this sad situation, try throwing something in the opposite direction of where you want to move. Conservation of momentum will hopefully save you.

Edit: I may have forgotten to answer your question. The only torque you will be able to make, by leaning forward or something, will make you rotate/fall over. The force is still pointing down because it is gravity making the torque. You will still be stuck in place.

For a sphere the case is similar, but as JMac points out, it should be specified.

With a sphere, with possibly non-uniform density we may have a torque. The force is still orthogonal to the ground, so the sphere is stuck. The torque will make the sphere rotate in its place. This will make the torque change, because mass distribution changes relative to a fixed frame of reference. Since there are no friction the system will be conservative and the sphere will rotate back and forth.

Comment: You seem to be approaching this from the perspective of a standing person, not a frictionless sphere.  My interpretation of his question was that if you had a sphere (we'll say it has non-uniform density) and placed it so that it was not balanced (i.e. CoM is not over the contact point of the ground) would it roll, or would it rotate in place?  Your edit suggests it would rotate in place, but assuming I interpret the question properly you might want to make it more explicit.